# importing items into urapidflow

Tags: magento

I am trying to write a php script that outputs to a csv file which then will get imported into urapidflow pro in magento. I'm a little bit confused when to use the fixed row format as oppose to a dynamic columns format. Is it possible to only stick to one format?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: please add sample output of desired file or ask from extension provider as this is a paid extension and you have better chance of getting any answers if you provide your current state or desired output format as potential answerers might not have access to this software you are using. It might just take in the regular magento export format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a hard time finding answers on the web, so for the sake of all I've decided to post the answer here.

Basically to have a successful product import you need 3 different types of csvs:

- [Product Import](http://www.unirgy.com/wiki/urapidflow/product_import)
- [Category Import](http://www.unirgy.com/wiki/urapidflow/category_import)
- [Fixed Row Format](http://www.unirgy.com/wiki/urapidflow/fixed_row_format)

Basically, for the product import csv, there are mandatory header columns which are highlighted in bold and red:

[image: mandatory columns]

The Fixed Row Format are exceptionally tricky. I played around with it until I figured out which attributes I want to be customizable for. Just for reference, these were the headers I used:

[image]

So, hope this helps, happy magento importing!